# Show SQL query results based on a count

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking for a way to only show results of a query based upon a count.  I have the following:

```
# Returns expected number
SELECT systems.hostname AS Hostname, systems.date AS "Last Checked In", count(systems2updates.2package) AS "Needed Updates" 
FROM systems2updates RIGHT JOIN systems on systems2updates.2hostname=systems.hostname 
GROUP BY systems.hostname;

# Shows all entires, including those with 0
SELECT systems.hostname AS Hostname, systems.date AS "Last Checked In", count(systems2updates.2package) AS "Needed Updates" FROM systems2updates 
RIGHT JOIN systems on systems2updates.2hostname=systems.hostname 
WHERE "Needed Updates" > 0 
GROUP BY systems.hostname;

# Returns nothing
SELECT systems.hostname AS Hostname, systems.date AS "Last Checked In", count(systems2updates.2package) AS "Needed Updates" 
FROM systems2updates RIGHT JOIN systems on systems2updates.2hostname=systems.hostname WHERE "Needed Updates" = 0 
GROUP BY systems.hostname;
```

Any assistance greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Did you look into the HAVING condition?

Comment: On a sidenote: right outer joins are considered hard to read and should be avoided. Use left outer joins instead.

Comment: Why is `systems2updates RIGHT JOIN systems` harder to read then `systems  LEFT JOIN systems2updates`? @ThorstenKettner

Comment: @Raymond Nijland: It isn't. Right outer joins are considered harder to read when multiple tables are involved, because we tend to read the `FROM` clause top down i.e. from left to right. So it's good to make it a habit not to use right joins.

Comment: Well with multiple tables it is indeed is harder to read @ThorstenKettner .. i also never use RIGHT JOIN's because not all database systems supports RIGHT join's. SQLIte is one off them.

Comment: @Kyle apologies about pinging you here, but one can't comment on deleted questions. The question I was trying to get an answer to is _how you intend to use_ the output you were requesting in your other, now-deleted question. If you just need to write that output to a file or let a human read it, great. If you're passing it over ssh or putting it on a command line, that's the opposite of great and you would be creating major security issues by using the output you asked us how to create; hence trying to get clarification before answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

`WHERE` limits the records you are using. The aggregation result `"Needed Updates"` does not exist at that moment. If you want to filter on aggregation results, use `HAVING`:

```
...
GROUP BY systems.hostname
HAVING "Needed Updates" = 0;
```

BTW: MySQL allows column aliases in `HAVING`. This is not allowed in standard SQL however, where you would have to `GROUP BY count(systems2updates.2package)`.

**UPDATE:** MySQL is not always standard-compliant when it comes to quotes.  Alias names in double quotes can be taken for a string by MySQL. Better avoid such alias names.

```
select 
  s.hostname as hostname, 
  s.date as last_checked_in, 
  count(su.2package) as needed_updates 
from systems s
left join systems2updates su on su.2hostname = s.hostname
group by s.hostname
having count(su.2package) = 0;
```

Comment: This still returns everything, regardless of the number of "Needed Updates":

Comment: Then it may be the quotes as pointed out in BWS's answer. Double quotes are standard delimiters for alias names, but in MySQL they may be considered string delimiters depending on certain settings. Better avoid alias names that need quotes altogether, e.g. use `needed_updates`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are looking to only return rows where the COUNT is greater than a certain value? If that's the case, the HAVING clause is the easiest way. For example:

```
SELECT sampleValue, COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.SomeTable
GROUP BY sampleValue
HAVING COUNT(*) > 5
```

Note that HAVING does not perform well, and you may want to look at an alternative solution using the ROW_NUMBER() function.

Comment: I am not able to translate this into a query with my fields.  Can you elaborate please?

Comment: Drop MSSQL's dbo object from the query. MySQL doesn't support ROW_NUMBER() untill MySQL version 8.0 + which is not product ready jet..

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER()` would be inappropriate here anyway. `HAVING` is what should be used. I don't see how some weird solution with `ROW_NUMBER()` could outrun the simple query with `HAVING`.